# creating a rounded button from AS3?

Tags: actionscript-3, flex3

How to create rounded & good looking "OK" and "CANCEL" buttons from AS3 ?

I dont want to use any images for these, just draw them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd use a Shape or a Sprite, and draw on it using the graphics proerty
something like

```
var s:Shape = new Shape();
s.graphics.beginFill(0x123123, 1);
s.graphics.drawRoundRect(...);
s.graphics.endFill();
```

or using a Sprite if you want to attach additional elements on it (like a label)

Answer (score 2):

Further to monkee's answer, if using [Flex](http://www.adobe.com/products/flex/) you can create very simple rounded [Buttons](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/mx/controls/Button.html) by setting the `cornerRadius` style.

Comment: That's what I'm going with personally.

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to do that.

If I were you - if a button is all you need. Make yourself a button class. If you need more Layout & GUI elements, consider using the [Flex Framework](http://www.adobe.com/products/flex/) or something like [ASwing](http://www.aswing.org/)

In Flex either learn [how to skin](http://scalenine.com/blog/2007/02/17/10-ways-to-skin-an-app/) a component or do it yourself. Just create a canvas, box, label or whatever with a picture in it and make it behave like a button.